# How can I view the history of a single branch in EGit for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When reviewing code in eclipse using EGit plugin, before merging it to the develop branch, you switch to the branch and see what files changed with the commits on that branch. For this I would like to see -only- the commits to the current checked out branch. When using Team -> Show in History, I get the complete history across all branches.

How can I view only the commits to the current checked out branch, instead of having to search trough the complete GIT history to find the relevant commits?

Using review tools like Gerrit are not an option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check the filter button in the [History View](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#History_View):

> All Branches

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/3/3b/Egit-0.9-history-view-allbranches.png]

> This toggle activates the "`All Branches`" mode.
>   By default, only those commits are shown in the commit log that can be reached from the currently checked out commit, i.e. the Commit Graph ends with the currently checked out commit and newer commits are not shown.
>   If this button is down, all commits will be shown in the commit log.
>   This is illustrated in the following picture from our example. The branch "beforeSplit" is currently checked out; by activating the toggle, the newer branches will become visible:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/c7/Egit-0.9-history-view-allbranchesToggle.png]

And you need to combine that with:

> "Additional Refs" toggles the visibility of certain Refs created during actions like fetch, rebase, merge, for example FETCH_HEAD, ORIGIN_HEAD... This can be helpful to remove clutter from the history view.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/0/0e/Egit-3.1-HistoryViewSettings.png]

Comment: @robross0606 OK. I have refreshed this 3-years old answer with the current documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[image: un-check check the "Additional Ref"]

You might need to un-check the "Additional Ref" option. please see the attached image.